# How to implement Interfaces from CompositePageTransformer class

Tags: java, kotlin

I just started studying Kotlin and tried to follow an example about `CompositePageTransformer` and `ViewPager2` but in example use JAVA. I am so confused about it. **The problem is I can't override `fun transformPage` on ViewPager2.PageTransformer**

### My Kotlin Code

```
val compositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()
    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(ViewPager2.PageTransformer {
         override fun transformPage(page: View,position: Float) {
                        val r = 1 - abs(position)
                        page.scaleY = 0.95f + r *  0.05f
                  }
    })
```

### ViewPager2.java

```
public interface PageTransformer {
        void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Java requires that all public classes/interfaces were placed into the same-named files. So, `public interface PageTransformer` should be placed into `PageTransformer.java` file (or had another visibility modifier).

Secondly, you call it from Kotlin in the wrong way. Correct syntax should be:

```kotlin
compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(object : PageTransformer {
    override fun transformPage(page: View, position: Float) {
        val r = 1 - abs(position)
        page.scaleY = 0.95f + r *  0.05f
    }
})
```

If you mark your interface with `@FunctionalInterface` and use Kotlin 1.4, then it could be even more concise:

```kotlin
compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(PageTransformer { page, position ->
    val r = 1 - abs(position)
    page.scaleY = 0.95f + r *  0.05f
})
```